Loop update through table with sum of one column dependent on table variables
Using Microsoft SQL Server I'm trying to evaluate a table and aggregate a column into a new column through an update/set command.  Is there any easier way to do this?
Data set to evaluate and desired result shown here:



Style
Color
QTY
Total for Style (Desired Result)




Style A
001
1
3


Style A
001
2
3


Style A
002
4
4



Code today:
UPDATE ECDB.dbo.INVFIFOLAYERING
SET OH_INV_LINE_UNALLOC = (SELECT SUM (A.OH_INV_LINE_ALLOC)
                           FROM INVFIFOLAYERING A
                           WHERE A.CD_STYLE = CD_STYLE 
                             AND A.CD_COLOR = CD_COLOR)

End result/error: I get the sum of all styles/colors in every column.

The problem is that this A.CD_STYLE = CD_STYLE is translated into this A.CD_STYLE = A.CD_STYLE. Because you don't fully qualify the column you are trying to match, SQL Server takes the nearest matching column. Instead fully qualify both columns, to correctly correlate the sub-query with the update statement e.g.
UPDATE i SET
    OH_INV_LINE_UNALLOC = (
        SELECT SUM (a.OH_INV_LINE_ALLOC)
        FROM dbo.INVFIFOLAYERING a
        WHERE a.CD_STYLE = i.CD_STYLE and a.CD_COLOR = i.CD_COLOR
    )
FROM dbo.INVFIFOLAYERING i;

Note 1: while its not necessary to alias the table you are updating as shown, in my opinion its clearer. And note the structure of the update statement changes slightly when aliasing the table being updated.
Note 2: you should always schema qualify your objects, not not database qualify them.
Note 3: You should also use aliases which represent the table they are aliasing a does not, whereas i or ifl does.
You could perform you update in a simpler way, using an updatable CTE with windowed sum e.g.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        SUM(a.OH_INV_LINE_ALLOC)
        OVER (PARTITION BY STYLE, COLOR) AS UNALLOC_CALC
    FROM dbo.INVFIFOLAYERING a
)
UPDATE cte SET OH_INV_LINE_UNALLOC = UNALLOC_CALC;


This worked perfectly and seems so simple now - thank you.

@SQLFinanceGuy123 are you familiar with "accepting" an answer?
